# Validation of object within a list in Parallel C#

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach, concurrent-collections

I'm implementing an import functionality, wherein I need to read the data from the user uploaded CSV or Excel file and run a few validations and sanitize the data before writing the data to DB.

I'm able to get the data from the file to a list of objects, with the following structure:

```
public class Order
{
    public string Sku { get; set; }

    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    public DateTime OrderFulfillmentStartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime OrderFulfillmentEndDate { get; set; }

    public string ValidationErrors{ get; set; }
}
```

Following are the validations that need to happen within the objects in the list, a few examples below:

1. No two orders with the same SKU and OrderFulfillmentStartDate, OrderFulfillmentEndDate are allowed.
2. No two orders with the same SKU and overlapping OrderFulfillmentStartDate, OrderFulfillmentEndDate are allowed.

etc.

**The way I implemented it:**

1. During the first encounter of a distinct record (passing all the validations AND "ValidationErrors" == string.empty), I'm adding the record to a temp list.
2. During the next iteration, I'm validating the currently processing record with the record present in the temp list, if the validation fails, I'm populating the "ValidationErrors" field and adding the temp list.

E.g:

[image]

Now coming to the crux of the issue:
**The size of the data can be around One Million rows**.

When I implemented the validations sequentially using foreach loop, the validation process is taking more than 8 hours. 
Having said that, I believe doing the validation in parallel would cut down the time needed drastically.

I did try implementing the logic using **Parallel.ForEach** and **Partitioner** concept. The processing did quicken up, but I'm not sure, how I can keep a temp list that can be used/updated by multiple threads in the ForEach loop, during the validation.

Is there is a better or quicker approach to achieve what I'm trying to do here? Please do let me know about it.

Thank You!

Comment: You may want to look into [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: 8 hours looks like a lot for just a million rows. Even if you were hitting the DB multiple times for each row. Can you provide more info on what you're doing to process this data? I'd guess there's more important things to optimize before going into parallel.

Comment: I did check that, but it didnot provide me lock during the writes, which led to dirty data.

Comment: If you're looking in the list itself to find itens with the same SKU, you could implement a lookup table with the SKU as key. This will optimize list access from O(N) to O(1).

Comment: @Ortiga Even I was surprised by the time taken. These are simple validations across few lists. Can you please guide me how to go about with the lookup table approach?

Comment: If you can run a test, how long does the entire process take if you DON'T write to the db? Just read from file and do your validations.

Comment: @JohanP it is taking around 8 hours. There are 10 validation steps that gets processed. Everything is in-memory.

Comment: In your processing step 2 from above, instead of adding to a list, you should add it to a `ConcurrentDictionary` , which will make you lookups O(1) as @Ortiga has mentioned.

Comment: @JohanP When I tried using the ConcurrentCollection DS like (ConcurrentBag), I encountered dirty data i.e. in the above example both the records with SKU 23354 had errors as "Overlapping Dates".

Comment: @user2697452 I'm on mobile right now, sorry if my formatting is off. But if you have a `List<Order> orders`, you can do `var lookup = orders.ToLookup(x => x.SKU);`. Then access all orders with the same SKU as `var ordersWithSameSku = lookup[SKU]`.

Comment: You need to make sure that you are using the concurrentdictionary correctly. That collection is thread safe and if you're getting dirty data, you need to have a relook at how you are checking/inserting keys. But as a test, don't parallelize your code and see if you get an improvement on it.

Comment: Forget about parallelism and `ConcurrentDictionary`. Just go with a normal `Dictionary` or a `Lookup`. Parallelism is useful when you want to squeeze a little bit of performance from an already fully optimized algorithm. Parallelizing an unoptimized algorithm is a waste of time.